# UITableView Header at the side of the table

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I want to make a tableView like this:
http://www.topappreviews101.com/ipappimg/4025/moma-ab-ex-ny-screenshot-3.jpg
I created a horizontal table view, and rotate every cell:
`self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( -M_PI/2 );
    self.tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;`
and
`cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI/2 );`

And my problem is: how to create horizontal header at the side of table (check picture plz)?

Comment: On the top or bottom? There is nothing on the side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UILabel` for that and rotate them in relative motion of your table on the same event.

Comment: I can add label at the first cell of every group and transform it. But it must be look like header with animated scroll. Sorry for my english) Check this video, plz: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYVvbuVjyfo   24sec, headers move

Comment: I'm not asking to add Label on cells, add them above to your cell and animate them separately.

Comment: Okey, if I can't use header, you solution seems to be the best way! Thx